# Good Development tool for windows ce

Tags: windows-ce

I'm just finding my feet on Windows CE development and have quite a few questions.

We're trying to develop apps on Windows CE (mobile computer with a barcode scanner) and I'm looking for development tools. I've an ASP.Net/WinForms background and I did build another app using C#/VS2008 and am looking to see if there is like a tool that can be used to expedite development. 
The app we're trying to do is of medium complexity and an ideal tool would be one that I could use in conjunction with lets says some C# forms that I can code myself.

I've looked at a few tools and most of them are tailored for simple apps, besides they do not give me the flexibility to add code and the options are fairly limited.

Is there a tool like the one I'm looking for, or a good tool that I can use for CE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The de facto standard development environment for Windows CE apps is Visual Studio 2008 Professional.  It provides tools and compilers for both native (C/C++) as well as managed (C# and VB.NET) applications.

Comment: Thanks - I do have VS2008 and did use it for one of our apps, but I wondering if there is a tool for rapid development. Also since I come from a web/winforms background I do not think that I've quite the right paradigm/design principles for doing mobile apps yet, maybe a good book could help too.